# How to disable QWebGL in QT5 build

Tags: qt5, cross-platform

I'm trying to build Qt5 from source so I can cross compile a program statically for another platform.

I'm using the following command in the configure:

```
./configure -opensource -static -platform linux-g++ -release -device linux-arm-xilinx-zynq-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/opt/Xilinx/SDK/2015.4/gnu/arm/lin/bin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi- -qt-xcb -nomake tests -nomake examples -no-opengl -nomake tests
```

There is a problem occurring in this build when the process gets to the QWebGL part of the code base. There are some errors thrown based on the source code.

I don't actually know if I need webGL, since I'm not really doing anything other than the base Qt classes and not doing any networking stuff. Is there a way for me to just skip this part entirely and build the rest of Qt? I know there's some way to disable certain modules, based on [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/configure-options.html), but I don't know what if any module corresponds to this WebGl thing.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Is it -skip webglplugin?